# Deal with "&" character contain in string in API call (in R)

Tags: r, string, api

I have to call an API and use parameters

```
c <- as.character("hello & salut")

api_request <- paste("http://api.com/?",
                    "parameter_1=",a,
                    "&parameter_2=",b,
                    "&parameter_3=",c
                    ,sep="")

api_request <-URLencode(api_request, repeated = TRUE)
```

Here is what the URL looks like:

```
print(api_request)
[1] "http://api.com/?parameter_1=48456&parameter_2=8975464&parameter_3=hello%20&%20salut"
```

As you can see, the "&" symbol in the parameter_3 is still there and is not encoded.

How to specify that the "&" symbol in my string (c) in not a parameter of my request ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your URL looks malformed to me.  It should be something like `http://api.com?parameter_1=a&parameter_2=b...` , in other words, the start of the query string is question mark, not an ampersand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I edited the question with the correct URL form. The issue is still there

Comment: You still haven't shown us the encoded URL.  I suspect that you're making the wrong API call and this has nothing to do with encoding.

Comment: Are you looking for `glue::glue("http://api.com/?{parameter_1}=a&{parameter_2}=b&{parameter_3}=c")` or `glue::glue("http://api.com/?parameter_1={a}&parameter_2={b}&parameter_3={c}")`

Comment: @Tim: I added the final URL in the question so you can see what it looks like

Comment: @Remi Take a look at my updated answer.  I think you need to specify `reserved=TRUE` as a parameter to `URLencode` (at least the one from the `utils` package).  It's default behavior is for `file` URLs, where `&` does not need to be encoded.  It _does_ need to be encoded for http.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the characters which will make up the URL of your API call.  One option is to use `URLencode` from the `utils` package:

```
a <- "48456"
b <- "8975464"
c <- as.character("hello & salut")

api_request <- paste("http://api.com/?",
                    "parameter_1=",a,
                    "&parameter_2=",b,
                    "&parameter_3=",c
                    ,sep="")

url <- URLencode(api_request, reserved=TRUE)

url
[1] "http%3A%2F%2Fapi.com%2F%3Fparameter_1%3D48456%26parameter_2%3D8975464%26parameter_3%3Dhello%20%26%20salut"
```

### Demo

Note from the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/URLencode.html) that we need to set `reserved` to true here, because the default behavior for `URLencode` is geared towards file URLs, where `&` does not need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried the URLencode function but I still have the issue.

Comment: Then edit your question and include the encoded URL which is failing.  Does it still have `&` and other non alpha characters in it?  If so, then you did something wrong.

Comment: @Remi I'm sorry for going back and forth so much, but I don't know the library that well (though I do understand URL encoding, which is why I answered).